# how to make my own mnist dataset?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Tensorflow mnist download mnist dataset for English digits , I'm working with mnist for Arabic digits and I have JPG !

how to convert JPG to my own  " t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz " and " t10k-lables-idx1-ubyte.gz"?

help me please , thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm working on arabic handwritten characters recognition using deep learning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to convert them into byte and tar format.  You can just feed them into the placeholder.

```
img = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None))

...

digit = scipy.ndimage.imread("arabic_digit.jpg")
feed_dict = {img:digit}
sess.run(model, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

if you have multiple digits just load them into a numpy array before feeding it into the feed dict.

```
digits = []
for digit_location in digits_list:
    digits.append(scipy.ndimage.imread(digit_location))
digits = np.asarray(digits)
feed_dict = {img:digits}
sess.run(model, feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

Comment: If there's nothing else that you need please mark the question as solved. Thanks.

Comment: what is digits_list?

Comment: steven, thanks for comments, but I have training dataset and testing dataset, how to implement it?

Comment: How to implement what? I would need you to be specific. digits_list is a list of locations of the images you wish to load.  If you mean a model like mnist you can see here https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros and here https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py

Comment: I have dataset folder with Tr for training dataset and Ts for a testing dataset, how to make these folders as my mnist ?

Comment: Assuming Tr is the name of the folder and it only contains images inside the folder you can do this.  digits_list = os.listdir("Tr") and use the above.  You'll need to import os.